# Why does ACTION_SEND not behave like gallery's share button?

Tags: android, video, android-sharing

I have implemented the following code to share video:

```
// Copy video file to Fileprovider directory.
final String destFile = …

// Build FileProvider uri.
final Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, AUTHORITY, destFile)

Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
sendIntent.setType("video/*");
Log.d(TAG, "Sharing " + sendIntent.getType() + " for " + uri);

String title = "Share this content with";
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, title);

if (null != sendIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager())) {
    activity.startActivity(chooser);
}
```

This code works and shows the chooser. When I select a messaging app like Telegram, I get to pick the destination conversation, but the video is sent as a file attachment, meaning that users only see a document icon and need to download it and open externally. However, the same video, using the OS system gallery, will open Telegram into their video editor where they can cut/edit the media and when sent will be visible inline in the conversation.

What am I missing to get the same behaviour? Looking through Android git repositories I don't see anything different from this to share content, so I don't know what I'm missing. The log I get with this code looks like

```
 Sharing video/* for content://com.app.android.fileprovider/share/video-a.mp4
```

So not only does it have the mime type but also the file extension could help. When I change the code to use a different mime type for images then I get the same behaviour, where the images get inlined into Telegram's chat.

Comment: Use LogCat to see what the `Intent` is that the "OS system gallery" is using. Please bear in mind that there is no "OS system gallery"; there are dozens, if not hundreds, of different gallery apps pre-installed on Android devices, and others available for download.

Comment: The Intent is the same `{act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=video/* flg=0xb080001 cmp=org.telegra    m.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity (has clip) (has extras)}`, using the same mime type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the culprit was the `FileProvider`. Once I removed the `FileProvider` and passed in directly `file://` URIs everything works.

Comment: It won't work on Android 7.0+, where the `file` scheme is effectively banned. Please note that you only granted Telegram read access to your content, so it is unclear what you were expecting Telegram to do with respect to editing the video.

Comment: Yes, until such time as you raise your `targetSdkVersion` to 24 or higher.